# Leading zero and decimal in Javascript Calculator app

Tags: javascript, decimal, zero, calculation

I built a simple calculator application for exercise purpose. However, I encounter some bugs as:

1. There should not be leading zeros if there is no decimal point. (i.e 023 should be 23)
2. A leading zero should be displayed if the number is less than one and greater than zero. (i.e .21 should be 0.21)
3. Only up to one decimal point is permitted in a number. (i.e 0.9... should be only 0.9)

Here is the source code in codepen: [this.link](https://codepen.io/jhtan15/pen/RBXwLy)

Source code in JS:

```
// Variables
  var viewer = el("#viewer"), // Calculator screen where result is displayed
    equals = el("#equals"), // Equal button
    nums = el(".num"), // List of numbers
    ops = el(".ops"), // List of operators
    theNum = "", // Current number
    oldNum = "", // First number
    resultNum, // Result
    operator; // Batman

  // When: Number is clicked. Get the current number selected
  var setNum = function() {

    if (resultNum) { // If a result was displayed, reset number
      theNum = this.getAttribute("data-num");
      resultNum = "";
    } else { // Otherwise, add digit to previous number (this is a string!)
      theNum += this.getAttribute("data-num");
    }

    viewer.innerHTML = theNum; // Display current number

  };

  // When: Operator is clicked. Pass number to oldNum and save operator
  var moveNum = function() {
    oldNum = theNum;
    theNum = "";
    operator = this.getAttribute("data-ops");


    equals.setAttribute("data-result", ""); // Reset result in attr
  };

  // When: Equals is clicked. Calculate result
  var displayNum = function() {

    // Convert string input to numbers
    oldNum = parseFloat(oldNum);
    theNum = parseFloat(theNum);

    // Perform operation
    switch (operator) {
      case "plus":
        resultNum = oldNum + theNum;
        break;

      case "minus":
        resultNum = oldNum - theNum;
        break;

      case "times":
        resultNum = oldNum * theNum;
        break;

      case "divided by":
        resultNum = oldNum / theNum;
        break;

        // If equal is pressed without an operator, keep number and continue
      default:
        resultNum = theNum;
    }

    // If NaN or Infinity returned
    if (!isFinite(resultNum)) {
      if (isNaN(resultNum)) { // If result is not a number; set off by, eg, double-clicking operators
        resultNum = "You broke it!";
      } else { // If result is infinity, set off by dividing by zero
        resultNum = "Look at what you've done";
        el('#calculator').classList.add("broken"); // Break calculator
        el('#reset').classList.add("show"); // And show reset button
      }
    }

    // Display result, finally!
    viewer.innerHTML = resultNum;
    equals.setAttribute("data-result", resultNum);

    // Now reset oldNum & keep result
    oldNum = 0;
    theNum = resultNum;

  };

  // When: Clear button is pressed. Clear everything
  var clearAll = function() {
    oldNum = "";
    theNum = "";
    viewer.innerHTML = "0";
    equals.setAttribute("data-result", resultNum);
  };

  /* The click events */

  // Add click event to numbers
  for (var i = 0, l = nums.length; i < l; i++) { //
    nums[i].onclick = setNum;
  }

  // Add click event to operators
  for (var i = 0, l = ops.length; i < l; i++) {
    ops[i].onclick = moveNum;
  }

  // Add click event to equal sign
  equals.onclick = displayNum;

  // Add click event to clear button
  el("#clear").onclick = clearAll;

  // Add click event to reset button
  el("#reset").onclick = function() {
    window.location = window.location;
  };
```

Anyone can do advice on the solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you encountering bug #1 in 'plus' operation only or all ?

Comment: Hi, I intend to change to 23 immediately once the user typed 023.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `parseFloat` and `toFixed` functions of javascript. Convert the string to float using parseFloat and check if it is an integer or rational number. Use toFixed to convert the number back to a string with 0 decimal points if it is an integer or with 1 decimal point if it is rational. It toFixed will take care of removing the leading zeros and appending a leading zero for numbers between 0 and 1.

You can use the following example:

```
var processNumString = function (str) {
  var floatNum = parseFloat(str);
  var res = floatNum % 1 == 0 ? floatNum.toFixed(0) : floatNum.toFixed(1);
  return res;
}
```

Here is the function with some example use

```js
var processNumString = function (str) {
    var floatNum = parseFloat(str);
    var res = floatNum % 1 == 0 ? floatNum.toFixed(0) : floatNum.toFixed(1);
    return res;
}

console.log(processNumString("22"));
console.log(processNumString("0022"));
console.log(processNumString("22.25"));
console.log(processNumString(".25"));
```